# whenever: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have RVM set up on my mahchine, and installed the "whenever" gem on my machine to run cron jobs. When I tried to execute the command:

```
 whenever --update-crontab store
```

I get this error:

```
-bash: whenever: command not found
```

I think a path issue is there. Kindly help me out.

Comment: check are u in same rvm path or try bundle exec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

command not found simply tells you that the gem is not there.  So it's better to print out all current installed gems.

```
gem list | grep whenever
```

If you don't have it in the result, then make sure you're in the right gemset (maybe you installed the gem in some other gemset).

```
rvm gemset list
```

If you find the other gemset should be the right one, then

```
rvm gemset use [gemset_name]
```

Comment: cron tab is set up using bundle exec. but its not running.

Comment: but the problem is not crontab, it's whenever

Comment: Use `gem list whenever` or `gem search whenever` instead of piping to grep.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan for the gem syntax.

Answer (score 17):

If the gemfile has whenever gem and bundle install has been done,
then use bundle exec for the right context.

```
bundle exec gem list whenever
bundle exec whenever <command>
```

Comment: I don't know why that worked but it did. Specifically, I typed "bundle exec gem list whenever", then "bundle exec wheneverize" and my config/schedule.rb file was created (which was was what I couldn't seem to make happen before)

Answer (score 2):

It's 2019 now but I ran into the same error today. This is what fixed it for me:

```
gem update --system
```